# Why is android studio reporting URL is not registered?

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cilsA.png)  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_ag-aMsJn408Yef_V0TbVC0GvRIbbuRRPd0uRgsNoM4/edit?usp=sharing

It's in red. I tried to solve it but I still can't resolve the error. :( I already found some similar questions around here but nothing helped me to solve this issue. I hope someone has an idea... ^.^

Comment: Hi Lovely,could you show us the all data of `activity_login.xml`.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I have added in the data. Thank You .

Comment: I mean, you tell me the entire `activity_login.xml` file data

Comment: Please take a look here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_ag-aMsJn408Yef_V0TbVC0GvRIbbuRRPd0uRgsNoM4/edit?usp=sharing

Thank You So Much!

Answer (score 0):

A valid XML file has only one root node.

Now It included LinearLayout and RelativeLayout.

You must put RelativeLayout and LinearLayout in a reasonable place.

You can do like this,but you need to change the location.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          tools:context="sg.edu.tp.uxidcomt.LoginActivity">

<!-- Login progress -->
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/login_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutDots"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_above="@id/layoutDots"
                android:alpha=".5"
                android:background="@android:color/white"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@null"
                android:next="NEXT"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_skip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@null"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:text="SKIP"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                tools:context=".LoginActivity"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello_world"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hi how do I change the location? Sorry I'm new to this. Thank You ^__^